# Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

Tags: android-studio

Anybody knows how to get around this issue while launching Android Studio?

I saw a Google ticket here, but it was not useful: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=164202

Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected node Pythonid; nodes=[org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal, org.jetbrains.plugins.javaFX, org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle, org.jetbrains.plugins.github, org.jetbrains.java.decompiler, org.jetbrains.idea.maven, org.jetbrains.android, org.intellij.intelliLang, org.intellij.groovy, org.editorconfig.editorconfigjetbrains, hg4idea, com.millennialmedia.intellibot, com.jivesoftware.robot.intellij.plugin, com.intellij.ui-designer-new, com.intellij.tasks, com.intellij.properties, com.intellij.modules.xml, com.intellij.modules.xdebugger, com.intellij.modules.vcs, com.intellij.modules.python, com.intellij.modules.platform, com.intellij.modules.lang, com.intellij.modules.json, com.intellij.modules.java, com.intellij.modules.androidstudio, com.intellij.modules.all, com.intellij.java-i18n, com.intellij.copyright, com.intellij, com.google.gct.testing, com.google.gct.login, com.google.gct, amailp.intellij.robot, TestNG-J, Subversion, JUnit, Git4Idea, Coverage, CVS]
    at com.intellij.util.graph.GraphGenerator.buildOuts(GraphGenerator.java:55)
    at com.intellij.util.graph.GraphGenerator.<init>(GraphGenerator.java:36)
    at com.intellij.util.graph.GraphGenerator.create(GraphGenerator.java:40)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.createPluginIdGraph(PluginManagerCore.java:543)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initializePlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:1126)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initPlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:1256)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.loadApplicationComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:348)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.<init>(ApplicationImpl.java:215)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.ex.ApplicationManagerEx.createApplication(ApplicationManagerEx.java:45)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.<init>(IdeaApplication.java:112)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:47)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: What happened when you reported this to the address given?

Comment: Android Studio does not include any Python support out of the box. I see Python in your list of plugins. How exactly did you install the Python plugin?

Comment: I recall selecting some plug-in update prompted by Android Studio. That's what caused this issue it seems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you have a corrupted installation file - completely uninstall Android Studio and download it again from the website.

Install the newly downloaded version of Android Studio on your system - the one you had previously downloaded is likely corrupt.

Here are the instructions to uninstall Android Studio completely. Note that some files may be located in a different location depending on where you chose to install and the versions you've been using so if something is not in its normal place, please let me know.

Please follow all of the steps below in order.

Run the uninstaller

The first step is to run the uninstaller. Open Control Panel by accessing it from the menu when you right-click the Start Button (This applies for Windows 8 systems). Then, under Programs, select Uninstall a Program. After that, click on Android Studio and press Uninstall. If you have multiple versions, uninstall them as well.

After you have uninstalled Android Studio, it is recommended that you restart before proceeding with the steps below.

Remove the Android Studio files

To delete any remains of Android Studio setting files, in Windows Explorer (The file browser in Windows), type this as the File Path:

C:\Users[YOUR WINDOWS USERNAME]

Replacing [YOUR WINDOWS USERNAME] with the username of your account on Windows. If you don't know your username, navigate to C:\Users and it will list all users on the system.

Here, delete .android, .AndroidStudio and any versions of this directory with versions on the end, .gradle and .m2.

Then, go to

C:\Users\Harry[YOUR WINDOWS USERNAME]\Roaming

and delete the JetBrains directory.

Finally, go to

C:\Program Files

and delete the Android directory.

Remove the SDK

To delete any remains of the SDK, in Windows Explorer, type this in as the File Path:

C:\Users[YOUR WINDOWS USERNAME]\AppData\Local

Here, delete the Android directory.

(Optional) Delete all previous projects

If you want to delete any of your previous projects, the directory where your projects are found is the AndroidStudioProjects directory. It is located in your root user file, C:\Users[YOUR WINDOWS USERNAME].

Hopefully this will now have deleted the Android Studio files and you can now try reinstalling the tools.

If you have any problems doing so, give me a shout :)

Comment: Yes, that's the approach I took. I looked for a solution for couple days, but could not find any. So, I ended up removing old installation and started from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

1st step please disconnect your internet connection and restart the studio.
If it is not working??? Do the following steps.

- Open the folder `bin` under the directory where you installed your Android Studio.
- Find the file `idea.properties` and open it with Notepad++/UltraEdit/other_edit_tools.
- Add `disable.android.first.run=true` as the final line and save the file.
- Restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `lib` folder `.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/marketplace`

or execute command

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/marketplace/lib
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution is:

1. Delete folder `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio`
2. Delete folder `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio`
3. Run AndroidStudio.

**Note:
Android Studio will be opened like fresh install.**

Answer (score 1):

To recover from this state, you need to remove the "python" folder that you find here:
~./AndroidStudio1.2/config/plugins

(Found at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=164202, worked for me)

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem in android studio in linux OS after install a plugin,i resolved this issue with deleted.AndroidStudio3.2 folder from Home Directory and other way you can go to this directory and delete the plugin that caused it .

**Directory : /home/your system's name/.AndroidStudio3.2/config/plugins .**

and for windows OS you must go to this Directory :

**C:\Users\your system's name.AndroidStudioPreview3.2\config\plugins**

**Note** : this directory is hidden and you must visible befor use it .

Answer (score 1):

I did faced this issue too, where it says to do this in my windows 10:

please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues in a windows error message.

It happened when i added some plugins in Android studio in Windows.

**It persisted in my machine until i opened my Android Studio as an administrator and then uninstalled the most recent Plugins from File > Settings > Plugins > Installed Plugins.**

What went wrong may be I added many plugins and applied all of them at once. May be i should have added one plugin at a time. Like install a plugin > apply that plugin and restart my Android Studio IDE in order to see it's effects.

Answer (score 1):

**MacOS**

My issue was with a plugin. I tried all sorts of ways of deleting Android folders using terminal. Nothing was working for me until I searched all instances of `AndroidStudio` in Finder and deleted each of them. After reinstalling everything worked great!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by removing an incompatile plugin located here: ~\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins.

I deleted the folder "marketplace"

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Go to

```
'C:\Users\your-user-name\AppData\Roaming\Google\'
```

**2)** Delete folder

```
'AndroidStudio4.1'
```

**3)** Then restart Android studio.

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I came with a new solution. Instead of uninstalling Android Studio and removing all related folders and losing your programming state on Android studio, and beside all these wasting your time, you should try this solution first which worked for me:
In my case the problem was the Windows. As it has crashed recently, I figured out the problem could be it, so I decided to restore the windows to the most recent point before Android Studio crashed. But the system restore tool didn't allow me to restore my system at all, and it said I should repair missing or corrupted system files first.
I first used [Microsoft System File Checker tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e) thread to fix the case, and guess what? after restarting the windows 10, all problems gone. No need for uninstalling the Android Studio or removing any plugins or even restoring the windows to an stable state.
Hope this work for you too.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

[error Android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5Dnx.png)

Hi everyone, I have this problem recently and I found the solution by deleting plugins which was corrupted in:

~AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2021.1\plugins

-EmmyLua
-Luanalysis

Answer (score 0):

Open the folder bin under the directory where you installed your Android Studio.
Find the file idea.properties and open it with Notepad++/UltraEdit/other_edit_tools.
Add disable.android.first.run=true as the final line and save the file.
Restart Android Studio.

It information helped for me

Answer (score 0):

**<<~ ~ ~ Quick Solution for Windows 10, Hope it will help ~ ~ ~>>**

- Download the latest Android Studio from the official website
- Uninstall the existing Android Studio from your computer. **NB: Remove Settings Preferences too while uninstalling.**
- Restart your computer
- Install the newly downloaded Android Studio
- Delete the old  directories which will show when run the Android Studio the first time after installation of the new Android Studio.

**NB: Do not remove your SDK files after uninstalling the Android Studio, if you want to save your time in installing the Android Studio.**

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem, depending on the system you use delete the following files:

```
Linux:
~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudioPreview4.1

Windows: 
C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioPreview4.1

MacOS:
~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudioPreview4.1
```

Thanks @Jonilson Coelho dos Anjos

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu users

1. go to home
2. press ctrl+h to show hidden folder .local
3. now go to .local folder
4. you will find share folder, go inside share folder
5. find Google folder and delete it
6. Open Android Studio
   Enjoy !!

Answer (score 0):

delete paid plugin in android studio plugin folder (C:\Users\your_computer_name\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins) and will work correctly. it works for me.

paid plugin should have to activate otherwise it will conflict.

Answer (score 0):

100 % solved

1st go to

- C:\Users\your-user-name\AppData\Roaming\Google\

2nd Delete folder

- List item
- 'AndroidStudio4.1'
- 'AndroidStudio4.1-backup'
- DELETE ALL ALL ANDROID STDIO VERSION AND BACKUP RELATED FOLDER

3rd Start again android studio